# 400 Caller's project doesn't match parent project

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-translate

I have this block of code that basically translates text from one language to another using the cloud translate API. The problem is that this code always throws the error: "Caller's project doesn't match parent project". What could be the problem?

```py
translation_separator = "translated_text: "
language_separator = "detected_language_code: "
translate_client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
# parent = translate_client.location_path(
        #     self.translate_project_id, self.translate_location
        # )
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = (
                os.getcwd()
                + "/translator_credentials.json"
        )

        # Text can also be a sequence of strings, in which case this method
        # will return a sequence of results for each text.
try:
            result = str(
                translate_client.translate_text(
                    request={
                        "contents": [text],
                        "target_language_code": self.target_language_code,
                        "parent": f'projects/{self.translate_project_id}/'
                                  f'locations/{self.translate_location}',
                        "model": self.translate_model
                    }
                )
            )
            print(result)
except Exception as e:
            print("error here>>>>>", e)
```

Comment: Where are you running the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be related to the authentication method that you are using on your application, please follow the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup#auth) for authention methods with the translate API. If you are trying to pass the credentials using code, you can explicitly point to your service account file in code [with](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code):

```
def explicit():
    from google.cloud import storage

    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'service_account.json')
```

Also, there is a [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-translation-python3/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) for getting started with the translation API with Python, this is a great step by step getting started guide for running the translate API with Python.

If the issue persists, you can try creating a [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for Google Support